# Can I wait until Monday to get work done if I'm on bereavement and PTO?

Tags: time-off, planning

I have taken this entire week off from work. Due to the holiday, a PTO day yesterday for my birthday, and 3 days bereavement due to my grandfather passing away, I will not be back in the office until June 1st.

I checked my e-mail today for the first time since Friday and I saw that my boss sent an e-mail talking about how we need to submit our "Where do you want to be in five years" plan. We've known for probably ~2 weeks that we had to do the plan and put it in our internal system, but they just finally sent out an example of how it should look and where we need to submit it.

The plan is due this Friday (May 29th) however I won't be back in the office until next Monday (June 1st). Is it acceptable for me to leave this until Monday to complete even though I'm on bereavement or should I try to submit something before Friday?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it acceptable for me to leave this until Monday to complete even though I'm on bereavement or should I try to submit something before Friday?

Most managers would be ok with something being late for reasons of bereavement, especially since you were out of office the entire time you had to work on it (due to them being slow).

I suspect if your manager was the type to not be ok, you wouldn't have thought to ask this question.

But really, only your boss can answer this. If you really are worried ask him.

Keep in mind if it's through a central system they may be able to run reports and your boss might get a "only 5/6 of your employees have completed this!" email. This is probably harmless, but might cause some annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your company.  If you feel you can do it and want to do it then go for it.  If you need this time to deal with grieving then do that.  Unless your boss is some kind of ogre they will understand this falls under work-life balance.